# How can I capture the group of digits at the end of a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, capture

I'm trying to capture the last digits in this line in a regex group:

The input:

```
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       54654
```

My pattern:

```
/Power_On_Hours.+Always\s.+([0-9]{1,5})/
```

I just can't seem to get it to capture "54654", it's returning undef :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, that capture group should grab '4', not undef. Your final `.+` will eat up everything until the last digit and then capture that to `$1`. This revision captures all the digits to `$1`:

```
/Power_On_Hours.+Always\s.+?(\d{1,5})/
```

The `?` makes the `.+` non-greedy, so it will match characters up to when the digits (`\d`) start to match.

Comment: Friedo, You are a god my friend.  That's it!

Answer (score 4):

As friedo pointed out, the trouble is that your last `.+` is greedy (the default behaviour) and you can fix it by changing it to `.+?`.

But I would probably use the `$` to match end of line, so:

```
/Power_On_Hours.+Always.+?(\d+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = q{9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       54654};

my ($interesting) = $s =~ /([0-9]{1,5})\z/;
print "$interesting\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

if your digits are always last ,

```
$string= q(9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       54654);
@s = split /\s+/,$string;
print $s[-1]."\n";
```

and if last digits can be any length

```
/.+Power.+Always.+[^\d](\d+)$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code also,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string= q(9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       54654);
my @array = split /\s+/,$string;

print "$array[$#array]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The last group of digits in the line, right?

```
my ($digits) = $input =~ /(\d+)$/;
```

The `$` sign anchors the group of one or more digits, `(\d+)`, to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:Power_On_Hours.+Always\D*)(\d+)
```

This worked on me

http://regex101.com/r/oS8sO5